# Gitlab: are "web pipelines" examples of "branch pipelines"?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I'd like to add a workflow rule to allow the pipeline to run when it is a "web pipeline" ([created by using Run pipeline button in the GitLab UI](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules)) and that the selected branch is main. So my first thought was to write:

```
if: $CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE == "web" && $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == $CI_DEFAULT_BRANCH
```

However, when reading the Gitlab doc, I am given to understand that `$CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is only available in "branch pipelines", see here:

> `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH`: The commit branch name. Available in branch pipelines, including pipelines for the default branch

The doc seems to define "**branch pipelines**" as pipelines that run when a push occurs in a branch, see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/merge_request_pipelines.html) and [there](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#use-predefined-cicd-variables-to-run-jobs-only-in-specific-pipeline-types):

> You can configure your pipeline to run every time you commit changes to a branch. This type of pipeline is called a *branch pipeline*.

> *Branch pipelines* that run for Git push events to a branch, like new commits or tags.

> Example: `if: $CI_COMMIT_BRANCH == "main"`: If changes are pushed to `main`.

(Note however that "branch pipelines" are not a type of pipeline in `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` (see [here](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html): `push`, `web`, `schedule`, `api`, `external`, `chat`, `webide`, `merge_request_event`, `external_pull_request_event`, `parent_pipeline`, `trigger`, or `pipeline`).)

Therefore, after carefully reading the doc, I can only conclude that "web" pipelines are not branch pipelines, since no commit or push was responsible for starting the pipeline, and therefore `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` will not available. So I started looking for another predefined variable that tells me the current branch name (unsuccessfully).

However, to my surprise, I can see by experimenting that `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` is in fact available in web pipelines! Isn't this incredibly confusing? So are `web` pipelines "branch pipelines" after all? Why? Which other types of `$CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE` are regarded as "branch pipelines"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’re comparing terms which are not mutually exclusive.

See the [predefined variables reference](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html).

The following are mutually exclusive variables:

- `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` - The commit branch name. Available in branch pipelines, including pipelines for the default branch. Not available in merge request pipelines or tag pipelines.
- `CI_COMMIT_TAG` - The commit tag name. Available only in pipelines for tags.
- [All variables specific to merge request pipelines](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/predefined_variables.html#predefined-variables-for-merge-request-pipelines)

This is totally separate from the action which triggered the build:

> `CI_PIPELINE_SOURCE`
> How the pipeline was triggered. Can be push, web, schedule, api,
> external, chat, webide, merge_request_event,
> external_pull_request_event, parent_pipeline, trigger, or pipeline.
> For a description of each value, see [Common if clauses for `rules`](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/jobs/job_control.html#common-if-clauses-for-rules),
> which uses this variable to control when jobs run.

If you trigger a build on main from the web gui, it doesn’t stop being on main. It just wasn’t triggered by a push event. But GitLab is still running the pipeline with your repo at a specific commit on a specific branch. If you manually trigger a tag build from the web or if you schedule a tag build, the source would reflect that (`web` or `schedule`) and `CI_COMMIT_BRANCH` would be unset, and `CI_COMMIT_TAG` would be set.

Comment: Thanks, this mostly makes sense. Except maybe *GitLab is still building a specific commit on a specific branch*, I don't know what "building a commit" means. Imo they should just clearly say that the pipeline remembers the branch name or not depending on how it was started, and this should be the definition of a "branch pipeline". So I don't agree that *This is totally separate from the thing which triggered the build*. It just happens that there are two ways to start a web pipeline, by either selecting a branch or a tag.

Comment: CI/CD runs using a specific version of the repository. This can either be a commit on a branch, or a merge request, or a tag. Maybe there are others, but I don't know of them. Those are the possible states of the *code*. Separately, you can trigger a *CI/CD run* a variety of ways. You can push code from your computer to gitlab. Or you can file a merge request. Or you can schedule a build. Or you can press the "run pipeline" button. Or you can trigger a build from a different repo. The *way you request that gitlab runs the pipeline* IS a different thing from the *state of the code being run*.

Comment: You can trigger any of the repo state builds (branch build, merge build, tag build) using any of the pipeline sources (push, web, schedule, api, external, chat, ...). Since you can trigger a {tag, branch, merge} build from any of the sources, how could they clearly state which variables will be available based on the *source*?

Comment: Thanks, I understand what you're saying. I think I would just beg to differ that "branches", "merge requests", "tags", ... are states of the code. The state of the code is a commit, period. Saying that you run the pipeline "on a branch" or not has nothing to do with the state of the code, it's just a Gitlab viewpoint. If I create a tag on a commit in a certain branch, why would the "state of the code" not be both a "tag" and a "branch"? It's about how you tell Gitlab to start the pipeline.

Comment: state of the code was the wrong term. but a tag and a branch are both ways of tracking commits. if you check out a tag, you will be in a headless state, not on a branch. so I disagree. in any case, this is irrelevant. I didn't design gitlab, but this is the way it works. so if the build corresponds to a tag, CI_COMMIT_BRANCH will not be defined; if you're on a branch build, CI_COMMIT_TAG will not be defined. I can't explain to you why gitlab is designed the way it is, but I can tell you that this is the way it will behave. Hope it's helpful!